# I DON'T want Windows 10 -- what should I do to dismiss reminder?

Tags: windows-7

Starting from today morning (at least in Poland) all my computers with Windws 7 started to showing a reminder, that I can reserver *free* future upgrade to Windows 10. Here is a Polish example:

[image]

On my home computer I registered, but on my office computer I was instructed to not reserve slot for future upgrade. However, no matter, what I do, reminder's icon in tray area (next to system clock) is always there. Closing or selecting anything brings no effect.

**How to get rid of this reminder, so it would be closed permanently and never show up again?**